# Does aws has any video service like vimeo?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-media-convert

Our Use Case :
some user will upload video on our platform .  Then  other people/user will watch those video. video quality will get change based on user internet speed

Our Current System :
After user upload video, we store the video on s3, then we use lambda for pulling that video from s3 and use media converter for converting video into HLS format and store the converted video to s3 .

Comment: @Anida I have the same use case. What did you rnd up with? Im wondering between storing on S3 (I guess + cloud fromt + aws media services) or external hosting service for videos. Do you have any insights? In terms of maintenance and pricing?

Comment: we went with vimeo, we find aws a  bit costly for video hosting, aws will charge you around 0.12 $ per GB data transfer out to the internet. Imagine a user upload a video which size was 2 GB, and this video was watched by 10000 users, so your s3 data transfer cost would be 10000*2*0.12 = 2400$ . Apart from the costing you have to configure everything by yourself . vimeo or any other video hosting service has many feature which reduce development time also cost less than aws

Answer (score 1):

AWS does not offer an 'end-user' video service like Vimeo. However, you could build one using Amazon S3 and various [AWS Media Services](https://aws.amazon.com/media-services/).

In fact, [Vimeo runs on AWS](https://vimeoott.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360022894914-Enterprise-FAQ).